# How dows Tapestry set Headers of a grid component?

Tags: header, grid, tapestry, tgrid

I was starting developping with tapestry and I have a question. Actually I have a question about the tables in tapestry and the headers of the tables. I know that if you have a Grid of User classes:

```
public class User {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}

<t:grid source="users" />
```

Tapestry would produce HTML similar to:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="firstName">First Name</th>
            <th class="lastName">Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td class="firstName">Traci</td>
            <td class="lastName">Lords</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my question is how did Tapestry set the values of the headers?

I mean how did tapestry set the value "First Name" from the class "firstName"?

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapestry uses reflection to get the names of your properties (`firstName` and `lastName`) then calls `TapestryInternalUtils.toUserPresentable(String id)` to convert it to a more human readable form.

From `toUserPresentable()` javadocs:

> Capitalizes the string, and inserts a space before each upper case character (or sequence of upper case characters). Thus "userId" becomes "User Id", etc. Also, converts underscore into space (and capitalizes the following word), thus "user_id" also becomes "User Id".

Comment: Note that TapestryInternalUtils.toUserPresentable(..) is a last resort. Tapestry will first try to find a localized property file for the user's language and will look for properties for firstName-label, lastName-label etc. http://tapestry.apache.org/localization.html

Comment: Thank you @uklance your answer is what I've discovered in my application. According to your message i guess that the correct way is to use a properties file with the "-label" suffix, better than let tapestry get the name from the Variable?

Comment: @ibaneight the choice is up to you. Horses for courses :). You might choose to rely on TapestryInternalUtils.toUserPresentable() for english but provide overrides for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I actually have a FindUsers.tml file and also the FindUsers.java associated class, and finally I've got a FindUsers.properties file with some properties.

In my FindUsers.properties i've got the firstName-label=First Name and lastName-label=Last Name

and these properties are selected in my grid headers.

I think the "-label" makes that tapestry selects this properties as headers.